Boostrap (v5.3) Carousel and Image Sizing
I'm really new to using Bootstrap and perhaps trying to do more than what I'm capable of handling but am truly trying to become a developer. Currently making a Photography website using bootstrap and having an issue resizing the images used in the carousel. The original size of the images are 1284 × 1572 pixels. I want the carousel to take the whole width not the entire vh of the page.[[eenter image description here
I've tried adding a min-height: 300px; but I'm looking to keep the center of the image visible in the carousel if that makes sense.
